# Adding OpenLayers CSS and JS files into Grunt Build command?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, openlayers-3, grunt-build-control

I am currently building a web application that I set up using Angular.js (similar to the first few minutes of [this video.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gLa2LxMdAPs)

I am then looking to add an OpenLayers 3 map to the views on these pages. I have copied the .css and .js files into the app/styles and app/scripts folders respectively and linked them in within the view.

This works fine when it comes to using Grunt Serve, it calls in all the correct files.

However, when it comes to use Grunt Build, it appears not to bring in these new .css and .js files. I imagine i am not compiling the files corretly but as i'm new to this I could do with a point in the right direction.